# Windows 10 Pro - Unaccounted System Commit Charge - Resource Exhaustion

Tags: windows-10, memory, crash

After idling overnight (I do not use/auto sleep or hibernate; only the display auto turns off after locking), my fully up-to-date Windows 10 Pro computer will fail to turn on the display upon mouse or keyboard activity the next day.  Instead, the computer crashes and reboots.  The Event Viewer shows many Error events related to low virtual memory, and Event 2004 "Resource-Exhaustion-Detector" is logged every 5 minutes for hours.

Event 2004 "Resource-Exhaustion-Detector" General

Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: sqlservr.exe (3020) consumed 343736320 bytes, svchost.exe (7036) consumed 133574656 bytes, and MsMpEng.exe (2688) consumed 110944256 bytes.

Event 2004 "Resource-Exhaustion-Detector" Details (SystemInfo only because that is where my question lies)

```
<SystemInfo> 
      <SystemCommitLimit>49033330688</SystemCommitLimit>
      <SystemCommitCharge>49031442432</SystemCommitCharge>
      <ProcessCommitCharge>1374498816</ProcessCommitCharge>
      <PagedPoolUsage>446369792</PagedPoolUsage>
      <PhysicalMemorySize>17100132352</PhysicalMemorySize>
      <PhysicalMemoryUsage>11527102464</PhysicalMemoryUsage>
      <NonPagedPoolUsage>605999104</NonPagedPoolUsage>
      <Processes>73</Processes>
</SystemInfo>
```

My breakdown of the above:

```
SystemCommitLimit = 49,033,330,688 = approx 48 GB = 16 GB RAM + 32 GB Pagefile
SystemCommitCharge = 49,031,442,432 = approx 48 GB
ProcessCommitCharge = 1,374,498,816 = approx 1.4 GB
PagedPoolUsage = 446,369,792 = approx 0.5 GB
NonPagedPoolUsage = 605,999,104 = approx 0.6 GB
```

**If the SystemCommitCharge = 48 GB yet all processes and drivers combined have committed less than 3 GB, what has committed the other 45 GB that is causing my computer to crash?**

All information that I can find regarding debugging this Event assumes that a process (ProcessCommitCharge) or a driver (PagedPoolUsage/NonPagedPoolUsage) is leaking the memory.  In my case, I have no idea where to start debugging this memory leak.

Comment: Sometimes memory leaks can be seen in task manager, you can add columns to the process tab if needed, watch for a program to start creeping up on memory usage. If it is a svhost,exe entry chewing memory, right click on it and select go to services, it will highlight all the services running under that particular instance of svhost.exe

Comment: SQLServer (except for the Developer and Express editions) preallocate a large memory footprint at start, so are you sure you have configured it to leave a little ram free for the OS? Of the processes you list, it is certianly suspect. If you look at it in Process explorer, do you get any hints as to where the issue lies?

Comment: This issue appears to only occur when the machine is locked and idle, so I have not been able to catch it "in the act" using Task Manager or Process Explorer. I've installed SQL Server Dev 2014, and it consistently has a 374 MB Commit Size with a 72 MB Working Set (this is a fresh install w/o databases yet). My assumption is that applications should increase ProcessCommitCharge and drivers should increase Paged/NonPagedPoolUsage, yet 45 GB of SystemCommitChage is unaccountable, and I'm stumped. My one hunch is that this has something to do with Windows Hello (Surface Pro 4 infrared camera).

Comment: @ScottJones, This issue was occurring with a Surface Pro 4 that had significant sleep and power management issues because it was an early adopter of Connected Standby using Intel Skylake (the first x86 chip to offer Connected Standby AFAIK). I gave up trying to debug the issue (I configured the computer to allow auto-sleep) before this question had any answers, so I don't know if the answer below would have solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Windows 10, but I had the exact same issue. Lots of physical memory (16GB), most of which was free, but a huge committed memory (25GB) that eventually triggered Out Of Memory errors. To resolve it:

- Grab Sysinternals Process Explorer.
- Run as Administrator.
- Add the column Page Faults and sort by that.
- In my case the top entry was RunSwUSB and it had something like 13 million entries!

I stopped that service and you can see the results immediately in the graph below.

[image: committed memory]